# Maven- Deploy file goal

Tags: maven

I have a maven project in which the some xlsx files get generated after the project run phase. These excel sheets are used by some other projects also. So I need to publish these excel sheet artifacts to remote|local repository.

I tried with the deploy plugin's deploy-file goal. But after deploying the excel sheet as a jar in repo, I tried extracting the jar and I could see the excel sheet got corrupted. Excel sheet converted to several XML files. ( Sheet1.xml, Sheet2.xml ..)

Maven command :-

**mvn clean deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///C:\repository -Dfile=Series.xlsx  -DpomFile=seriesXL.pom**

SeriesXL.pom:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.pjt</groupId>
  <artifactId>seriesXL</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>*.xlsx</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>

</build> 


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. All inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is trying to push new file formats that are using ZIP and XML in their office suites. This method reduces the size of the file by around 50%.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/06/01/424085.aspx)

That means the excel file is actually a packed file of different xmls and other metadata informations.

I have done a work around to resolve the issue:

1. After excel sheet generation, I have added that file to a zip (SeriesXL.zip), using `java.util.zip.ZipEntry`.
2. Then deploy the zip file using the command

   ```
   mvn clean deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///C:\repository -Dfile=SeriesXL.zip -DgroupId=com.test.pjt -DartifactId=seriesXL -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
   ```

I am able to successfully deploy the SeriesXL.jar in local repository and while extracting the jar, I could see the original version of the Excel sheet, not just a bundle of XML files.

BTW Thanks Dunni for your support.

Answer (score 1):

This is because with the deploy-file command your pom is ignored. You have to run mvn deploy, so that the maven-jar-plugin is called (it is as default called in the package phase).

With your command, you're deploying the xslx directly into your repository, and i suspect it is handled as a jar, thus you get the xml, if you unpack the jar (because a xlsx is also just a packed file, that consists of various xml files).

I'd recommend you read some docs about the Maven lifecycles etc. ([Maven Lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my project requirement is like, build the project first,deploy the pjt jar to nexus repo,  then run the unit tests and finally invoke Main() method. After successful execution of the project, an excel sheet get generated dynamically(which contains some pjt info). These information should be available to other projects also. That is why, I tried to manually publishing that excel sheet alone as an artifact in nexus. I used the packaging scheme as 'Jar'. Will it be possible to create a jar which contains the excel sheet in its original format ?

Comment: Maybe the following command will work: mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///C:\repository -Dfile=Series.xlsx -DgroupId=com.test.pjt -DartifactId=seriesXL -Dversion=1.0

Comment: I tried the above mentioned deploy-file goal and able to create a jar file. But while extracting still the excel got corrupted.

Comment: Extraction log :-C:\repository\com\test\pjt\seriesXL\1.0>jar -xvf seriesXL-1.0.jar
 inflated: _rels/.rels
 inflated: [Content_Types].xml
 inflated: docProps/app.xml
 inflated: docProps/core.xml
 inflated: xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin
 inflated: xl/printerSettings/printerSettings2.bin
 inflated: xl/sharedStrings.xml

Comment: inflated: xl/styles.xml
 inflated: xl/theme/theme1.xml
 inflated: xl/workbook.xml
 inflated: xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
 inflated: xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
 inflated: xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels
 inflated: xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml
 inflated: xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.rels
 inflated: xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml
 inflated: xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml
 inflated: xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml